# transfer Sepolia faucet using an API

Tags: sepolia

I need an urgent solution.

I am working on a functionality that creates wallets for users and fund them with some `sepolia` faucet for a transaction- is there any api that I can use to transfer `sepolia`?
transferring `sepolia` between 2 accounts will also work.

Thanks

Comment: Using `sendTransaction` with an amount and the recipient address should work to transfer sepolia ether.